# Installing the php memcached extension on CentOS 6.4

Tags: php, memcached

So I have installed the memcache(d) service and now I want to install the **memcached** php extension. Note the d... I don't want to install memcache. I currently have the memcache php extension installed.

I am following this official guide: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewInstallFromSource

However, when I run the

```
make && make test
```

command I get the following errors:

```
prove ./t
make: prove: Command not found
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

What does this mean? How can I fix this and install memcached?

Answer (score 3):

Run :

```
yum provides *bin/prove
```

So, install `perl-Test-Harness`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is just saying that the command "prove" wasn't found. Either it's not in your path or it isn't installed.

Use `find` or `locate` to check for prove. Use `echo $PATH` to check which directories are searched in for commands.